# pytest-allure attachment from outside the test/conftest.py (closed)

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am using pytest-allure plugin and allure-docker-service.
I would like to attach a jpeg file from a function that my test calls (and not directly inside the test or conftest), is that an option? cause i don't get any Exception, it just does not appear as an attachment.

This is the line inside the function which is called directly from the tets.

`allure.attach.file(full_path, "Out of Focus Preview Image", allure.attachment_type.JPG)`

Thanks

Comment: It is an option.  I always use allure.attach instead of allure.attach.file but allure.attach.file should work.  Are you sure the attachment is not buried in the execution stack?

Comment: my mstake.. i messed up with the if statements.
how do you use attach for jpg files?

Comment: Something like...
with open(your_file_path) as f:
    allure.attach(f.read(), "description", allure.attachment_type.JPG)

But have you checked the report to verify the attachment isn't buried in the call stack somewhere?  allure.attach and allure.attach.file should be doing the same thing.